# How to add javascript variables to a HttpServletResponse

Tags: javascript, java, variables, servlets, nashorn

I am having a bit of a struggle with something:

I am executing a Javascript script in my servlet (using nashorn) and, in the HttpServletResponse, I want to retrieve the value of javascript variables defined on that script execution, so they can be used in the page render in the client's browser.

I can't find a way to add javascript variables to the response.

I am using Java for the servlet, and plain HTML5 and javascript for the webpage.

Comment: post your code so we can help...

Comment: you can use request.getParameter("ATTRIBUTENAME") in your serverlet